# Some webpages not loading in android's webview

Tags: android, webview, instagram

I have been trying out the instagram API. I don't understand why the authorization page does not load in my webview. Other pages like yahoo and google load properly.

here is my code

```
public class LogInFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String AUTHURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";

public static String CALLBACKURL = "https://www.google.com";

private static final String CLIENT_ID = "02c86b5fe4a648a0a6a47966a7bac9cb";

public LogInFragment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.d("LogInFragment", "Fragment Created");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    Log.d("LogInFragment", "In onCreateView");
    String auth_URL = AUTHURL + "?client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&redirect_uri="+CALLBACKURL+"&response_type=code";

    WebView loginView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.loginWV);
    loginView.setWebViewClient(new authWebViewClient());
    loginView.loadUrl(auth_URL);
    Log.d("LogInFragment", auth_URL);
    return view;
}

private class authWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (url.startsWith(CALLBACKURL)) {
            Log.d("LogInFragment", "CALLBACK called");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
            String[] urlPart = url.split("=");
            String code = urlPart[1];
            intent.putExtra("code", code);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        Log.d("LogInFragment", "CALLBACK notcalled");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to enable the javascript:

```
loginView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```